# marginnote always on right side of the page

Tags: positioning, double-sided, marginpar

My documentclass is `book`, so I've got an even and odd sides. I like that the equation number are always aligned on the right side - independent of the page (even/odd).
I started using marginnotes. I wanted to do the same, that the notes are always on the right side of the page?
How do I do that?

Comment: I know, you asked for the standard class `book` and Gonzalo Medina has already presented a brilliant answer, but with the KOMA-script class `scrbook`it would be a simple class option: `\documentclass[twoside=semi]{scrbook}`. I don’t know the class `memoir`, but I wouldn’t be surprised, when there were a similar option. In general both in KOMA-script and in `memoir` there are a lot of settings available as simple options or commands, which need massive redefinition in a standard class, cf. Gonzalo’s answer.

Answer (score 23):

Here's one possible solution patching (with the help of the `etoolbox` package) the LaTeX kernel command `\@addmarginpar`:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}
\usepackage[centering,marginparwidth=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@addmarginpar}{\ifodd\c@page}{\ifodd\c@page\@tempcnta\m@ne}{}{}
\makeatother
\reversemarginpar

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test Chapter One}
\section{Test Section}
\lipsum[2]\marginpar{test marginnote one}
\lipsum[2-4]\marginpar{test marginnote two}
\lipsum[2-4]\marginpar{test marginnote three}
\lipsum[4-5]]\marginpar{test marginnote three}
\lipsum[6]

\end{document}
```

[image]

With this layout for marginnotes, it's convenient to activate the `centering` option for the `geometry` package; further adjustments might be needed so that marginnotes on even pages can be correctly displayed on a printed document.

The above code provides a solution for the standard LaTeX `\marginpar` command; if `\marginnote` (from the `marginnote` package) is used instead of `\marginpar` to produce the margin notes, then the internal macro `\@mn@@@marginnote` will have to be redefined:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}
\usepackage[centering,marginparwidth=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\long\def\@mn@@@marginnote[#1]#2[#3]{%
  \begingroup
    \ifmmode\mn@strut\let\@tempa\mn@vadjust\else
      \if@inlabel\leavevmode\fi
      \ifhmode\mn@strut\let\@tempa\mn@vadjust\else\let\@tempa\mn@vlap\fi
    \fi
    \@tempa{%
      \vbox to\z@{%
        \vss
        \@mn@margintest
        \if@reversemargin\if@tempswa
            \@tempswafalse
          \else
            \@tempswatrue
        \fi\fi
          \rlap{%
            \ifx\@mn@currxpos\relax
              \kern\marginnoterightadjust
              \if@mn@verbose
                \PackageInfo{marginnote}{%
                  xpos not known,\MessageBreak
                  using \string\marginnoterightadjust}%
              \fi
            \else\ifx\@mn@currxpos\@empty
                \kern\marginnoterightadjust
                \if@mn@verbose
                  \PackageInfo{marginnote}{%
                    xpos not known,\MessageBreak
                    using \string\marginnoterightadjust}%
                \fi
              \else
                \if@mn@verbose
                  \PackageInfo{marginnote}{%
                    xpos seems to be \@mn@currxpos,\MessageBreak
                    \string\marginnoterightadjust
                    \space ignored}%
                \fi
                \begingroup
                  \setlength{\@tempdima}{\@mn@currxpos}%
                  \kern-\@tempdima
                  \if@twoside\ifodd\@mn@currpage\relax
                      \kern\oddsidemargin
                    \else
                      \kern\evensidemargin
                    \fi
                  \else
                    \kern\oddsidemargin
                  \fi
                  \kern 1in
                \endgroup
              \fi
            \fi
            \kern\marginnotetextwidth\kern\marginparsep
            \vbox to\z@{\kern\marginnotevadjust\kern #3
              \vbox to\z@{%
                \hsize\marginparwidth
                \linewidth\hsize
                \kern-\parskip
                \marginfont\raggedrightmarginnote\strut\hspace{\z@}%
                \ignorespaces#2\endgraf
                \vss}%
              \vss}%
          }%
      }%
    }%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test Chapter One}
\section{Test Section}
\lipsum[2]\marginnote{test marginnote one}
\lipsum[2-4]\marginnote{test marginnote two}
\lipsum[2-4]\marginnote{test marginnote three}
\lipsum[4-5]\marginnote{test marginnote three}
\lipsum[6]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice answer! Instead of patching the `\marginpar` command, is it possible to define a new command, e.g., `\rightmarginpar`? I'm using `\marginpar` to define a side note command, which I would like to be always on the right margin, but I don't want to modify `marginpar` because it may affect other commands. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I tried your answer in a memoir document but it does not work :(

Comment: A recent update of the `marginnote` package (2018/04/13) has changed the way `\@mn@@@marginnote` is defined. That method now gives errors reporting that `\marginnoterightadjust` is undefined. If I'm not beaten to it, when I have a fix to this I'll post it as a new answer below.

Comment: How can this patch be used for `sidenotes` also?

Answer (score 10):

Further to my comment a few days ago, if you are using the version of the `marginnote` package dated 2018/04/13 (or newer, at the time of writing), then you need to redefine `\@mn@@@marginnote` in a different but entirely analogous way.

For those who want to understand what's going on, the code below (and in the answer above) is the half of the definition from `marginnote` that handles marginnotes in the right hand margin (note the commented-out line `\if@tempswa` below is what used to find whether we're using an odd or even page: I left this line in to help anyone who is curious).

So, the code below, inserted in your preamble, should be compatible with `marginnote` versions since April 2018.

```
\makeatletter
\long\def\@mn@@@marginnote[#1]#2[#3]{%
  \begingroup
    \ifmmode\mn@strut\let\@tempa\mn@vadjust\else
      \if@inlabel\leavevmode\fi
      \ifhmode\mn@strut\let\@tempa\mn@vadjust\else\let\@tempa\mn@vlap\fi
    \fi
    \@tempa{%
      \vbox to\z@{%
        \vss
        \@mn@margintest
        \if@reversemargin\if@tempswa
            \@tempswafalse
          \else
            \@tempswatrue
        \fi\fi
        %\if@tempswa
          \rlap{%
            \if@mn@verbose
              \PackageInfo{marginnote}{xpos seems to be \@mn@currxpos}%
            \fi
            \begingroup
              \ifx\@mn@currxpos\relax\else\ifx\@mn@currxpos\@empty\else
                  \kern-\dimexpr\@mn@currxpos\relax
              \fi\fi
              \ifx\@mn@currpage\relax
                \let\@mn@currpage\@ne
              \fi
              \if@twoside\ifodd\@mn@currpage\relax
                  \kern\oddsidemargin
                \else
                  \kern\evensidemargin
                \fi
              \else
                \kern\oddsidemargin
              \fi
              \kern 1in
            \endgroup
            \kern\marginnotetextwidth\kern\marginparsep
            \vbox to\z@{\kern\marginnotevadjust\kern #3
              \vbox to\z@{%
                \hsize\marginparwidth
                \linewidth\hsize
                \kern-\parskip
                \marginfont\raggedrightmarginnote\strut\hspace{\z@}%
                \ignorespaces#2\endgraf
                \vss}%
              \vss}%
          }%
      }%
    }%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother
```

Comment: I'm sorry to be a pain, but can I ask: what would I need to change in this block to make all notes appear *on the left margin*? As you say, the old solutions no longer work. This works, but obviously puts all the notes on the right side. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've posted a parallel question about the left margin [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/472728/marginnote-always-on-left-side-of-the-page). If you are up for it, post an adjusted answer there, and I'll gladly accept it.

Answer (score 3):

I met the same question recently, and I found a simple solution in `geometry` manual. All I need is to add the option `asymmetric`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{verbose, a4paper, twoside, showframe, asymmetric}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\begin{document}

\chapter{}

Hello, \LaTeX.
\marginpar{Hello, \TeX.}

\newpage

Hello, \LaTeX.
\marginpar{Hello, \TeX.}
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]