# Marginnote on left side only, using document class book with twoside

Tags: double-sided, marginpar

I'm trying to use `marginnote` on document class `book` with `twoside`, but I can't see to get the margin notes strictly on the left.  I don't want to be putting `\reversemarginpar` on all the odd pages.  Can someone help me or direct me to help please.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/5764) It's always good to provide add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/5764) that illustrates your problem. That speeds up providing solutions since the community does not have to create their own from scratch.

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69595/marginnote-always-on-right-side-of-the-page

Answer (score 19):

You can use the `etoolbox` package to patch the `\@mn@margintest` command to set `\if@tempswa` to be always true and then issue a global `\reversemarginpar`:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}
\usepackage[centering,marginparwidth=2.5cm,paperheight=10cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@mn@margintest}{\@tempswafalse}{\@tempswatrue}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@mn@margintest}{\@tempswafalse}{\@tempswatrue}{}{}
\reversemarginpar 
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]\marginnote{test test test test test}
\lipsum[1-2]\marginnote{test test test test test}
\lipsum[1-2]\marginnote{test test test test test}
\lipsum[1-2]\marginnote{test test test test test}
\lipsum[1-2]\marginnote{test test test test test}
\lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Gonzalo Medina, thank you so much!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! It works perfect!

Comment: If you want it on the right instead, leave off the `\reversemarginpar` in Gonzalo's answer. I'm mentioning this because it took me a bit to figure it out. Also it is much simpler than Gonzalo's answer to the same problem [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69595/marginnote-always-on-right-side-of-the-page). (This should be a comment, but I don't have have enough reputation.)

Comment: This solution has recently stopped working with an updated version of marginnote I think...

Comment: Can this patch be used with `sidenotes` also?