# How to create twoside book with oneside margin?

Tags: margins, double-sided, marginpar, tufte

I want to make a twoside book with oneside margin such:

odd pages:
[image]

even pages:
[image]

full header, with margin figure(or table):
[image]

I used `tufte-book` class, but cannot set margins as i need. It's margins is in odd pages on the right and in even pages, on the left side of papers. I want the margins stay oneside(left or right) of papers, in both odd and even pages.

Comment: Just to clarify- are you using `tufte-book`, or is this something you tried and dismissed? If you are using it, can you change 'I used...' to 'I am using...'

Comment: No, I used `tufte-book` but cannot change margin settings as i need. If it is possible to customize margins in `book` class, it is better for me. Else i must use `tufte-book` or any other class.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First you have to define a layout with enough margin space.

```
paperwidth=170mm, paperheight=240mm, left=142pt, top=40pt, textwidth=280pt, marginparsep=20pt, marginparwidth=100pt, textheight=560pt, footskip=40pt
```

The asymmetric layout is a little bit tricky. If I understand correctly, you want the margin and text width to be the same, but the page is shifted towards the outer edge. This can be achieved with a binding offset.

```
bindingoffset=30pt,asymmetric
```

the latter option makes the margin always appear on the same side. Now, you have to switch the `\marginpar`s to appear at the inner side, this is done with the

```
reversemarginpar
```

option. I also used `showframe` to make everything more obvious. In total:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[paperwidth=170mm, paperheight=240mm, left=142pt, top=40pt, textwidth=280pt, marginparsep=20pt, marginparwidth=100pt, textheight=560pt, footskip=40pt,bindingoffset=30pt,showframe,asymmetric,reversemarginpar]{geometry}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
~\newpage
\marginpar{\lipsum[3]}\lipsum[2]
\clearpage
\marginpar{\lipsum[3]}\lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

which gives you

[image]

It is not clear, whether you want `tufte-latex` or not. Please provide an MWE and I will try to edit the answer.

EDIT:
If you are willing to try something new, you might like `sidenotes`. It is a package I made to add the T-L functionality to normal LaTeX classes. You can get the newest version on [github](https://github.com/andythomas/TeX-sidenotes/tree/master/latex). So in principle, a question such as 'How to do that in T-L' becomes 'How to do that in LaTeX'. This should give you a lot of options. In your particular case:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{sidenotes}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[paperwidth=170mm, paperheight=240mm, left=142pt, top=40pt, textwidth=280pt, marginparsep=20pt, marginparwidth=100pt, textheight=560pt, footskip=40pt,bindingoffset=30pt,asymmetric,reversemarginpar]{geometry}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
~\newpage
\lipsum[1]
\begin{marginfigure}
\includegraphics[width=100pt]{rectangle}
\caption{I am a figure}
\end{marginfigure}
\lipsum[2]
\clearpage
\begin{margintable}%
    \small
    \begin{tabular}{lll}
     Hg&Sn&Pb \\
    0.50&0.47&0.48\\
  \end{tabular}
    \caption{I am a table.}%
\end{margintable}%

\lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

which gives you:

[image: example output with sidenotes]

I do not know the answer to your second question off-hand, but `\begin{adjustwidth}` should be a good starting point. With the `sidenotes` package you might be able to look for a generic LaTeX answer and use that.

Comment: Thank you @Andy. I want to have `margin figure` and `margin table` and ... than you can see now in my (edited) question. I think i must use `tufte-book` class. What do you think?

Comment: And also, how to set header's width as fill the 100%? I mean that the header is stretched over the screen(text+margin).

Comment: @mohammadazadi: If you want to use the `tufte-book` class and just modify the margins, you can use the `\geometry` command:  `\geometry{paperwidth=170mm, paperheight=240mm, left=142pt, top=40pt, textwidth=280pt, marginparsep=20pt, marginparwidth=100pt, textheight=560pt, footskip=40pt, bindingoffset=30pt, showframe, asymmetric, reversemarginpar}`. If you like `tufte-book`'s margins, you can specify only the ones you want to change: `\geometry{bindingoffset=30pt, asymmetric, reversemarginpar}`.

Answer (score 0):

Example in the margin

```
\documentclass[twoside=semi]{scrbook}

\usepackage{xcolor}                 % to have colors 
\usepackage{lipsum}                 % for sample text
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}     % for customizing sections
\usepackage{amsmath}                % for mathematical content
\usepackage[amsmath]{ntheorem}      % for theorem-like environments

\usepackage[paperwidth=170mm, paperheight=240mm, left=142pt, top=40pt, textwidth=280pt, marginparsep=20pt, marginparwidth=100pt, textheight=560pt, footskip=40pt
%,bindingoffset=30pt
%,asymmetric
,reversemarginpar
,showframe]{geometry}


% customize section
\titleformat{\section}%
            {\Large\bfseries}% format
            {\llap{% label
               \thesection\hskip 9pt}#1}%
            {0pt}% horizontal sep
            {}% before

% customize subsection
\titleformat{\subsection}%
        {\bfseries}% format
        {\llap{% label
           \thesubsection\hskip 9pt}#1}%
        {0pt}% horizontal sep
        {}% before


% margin theorem
\makeatletter
\newtheoremstyle{mymargin}%
{\item[\theorem@headerfont \llap{##1 ##2}]}%
{\item[\theorem@headerfont \llap{##1 ##2}| ##3\theorem@separator\hskip\labelsep]}%
\makeatother

% my definition
\theoremstyle{mymargin}
\theorembodyfont{}      % customize these to suit your tastes
\theoremsymbol{}
\theoremprework{}
\theorempostwork{}
\theoremseparator{}
\newtheorem{mydefinition}{Example}
\numberwithin{mydefinition}{chapter}

\begin{document}
\chapter{My chapter}
\section{First section}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{mydefinition}
\lipsum[2]
\begin{equation}\label{eq:myequation}
    f(x)=x^2
\end{equation}
Test reference: \eqref{eq:myequation}
\end{mydefinition}

\section{Second section}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{mydefinition}
\lipsum[2]
\begin{equation}\label{eq:myequation}
    f(x)=x^2
\end{equation}
Test reference: \eqref{eq:myequation}
\end{mydefinition}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

@Andy's answer works great with `\marginpar`, but not if the latter is replaced by  `\marginnote`, in which case the margin notes appear left/right on alternating pages, instead of all left. If for some reason one needs to use `\marginnote`, a patch may be found here:

[Marginnote on left side only, using document class book with twoside](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73102/marginnote-on-left-side-only-using-document-class-book-with-twoside)