# distinguish between symmetric and asymmetric page layouts

Tags: best-practices, geometry

In order to fix a bug in the new version of the `sidenotes` package ([bug reported here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/170248/wrong-position-of-caption-in-odd-page-with-sidenotes-in-figure)), I made the following environment:

```
\newenvironment{autoadjustwidth}[2]%
{\ifthenelse{\boolean{@twoside}}%
{\begin{adjustwidth*}{#1}{#2}}%
{\begin{adjustwidth}{#1}{#2}}%
}%
{\ifthenelse{\boolean{@twoside}}%
{\end{adjustwidth*}}%
{\end{adjustwidth}}%
}%
```

The `autoadjustwidth` environment tries to distinguish between book/twopage/symmetric and article/'all pages similar' styles. Can I rely on `@twoside` to detect this?

Full MWE for one particular case, where a figure fills the textcolumn plus the margin:

```
%\documentclass{article}
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\newlength{\overhang}
\setlength{\overhang}{\marginparwidth}
\addtolength{\overhang}{\marginparsep}

\newlength{\full}
\setlength{\full}{\textwidth}
\addtolength{\full}{\overhang}

\newenvironment{autoadjustwidth}[2]%
{\ifthenelse{\boolean{@twoside}}%
{\begin{adjustwidth*}{#1}{#2}}%
{\begin{adjustwidth}{#1}{#2}}%
}%
{\ifthenelse{\boolean{@twoside}}%
{\end{adjustwidth*}}%
{\end{adjustwidth}}%
}%
\makeatother

\renewenvironment{figure*}[1][htbp]{%
\begin{figure}[#1]%
\begin{autoadjustwidth}{}{-\overhang}}%
{\end{autoadjustwidth}%
\end{figure}}%

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure*}
\includegraphics[width=\full, height=100pt]{example-image-a}
\end{figure*}
\lipsum[3]
\newpage
\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure*}
\includegraphics[width=\full, height=100pt]{example-image-a}
\end{figure*}
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`@twoside` is exactly the boolean to detect whether the document is two sided or not.  It is part of the latex kernel.  If you load `etoolbox` then you can test it with `\ifbool`:

```
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{autoadjustwidth}[2]%
{\ifbool{@twoside}%
{\begin{adjustwidth*}{#1}{#2}}%
{\begin{adjustwidth}{#1}{#2}}%
}%
{\ifbool{@twoside}%
{\end{adjustwidth*}}%
{\end{adjustwidth}}%
}%
\makeatother
```

Note that the `scr` classes have an extra option of setting `twoside=semi`.  This results in a mixed typesetting scheme with some two sided features but where margin notes are always placed on the same side.  This value is tested with `\ifbool{@semitwoside`.  The `twoside=semi` option results in `\@twosidetrue` and `\@semitwosidetrue`; `twoside` or `twoside=true` gives `\@twosidetrue` and `\@semitwosidefalse`; `oneside` or `twoside=false` gives `\@twosidefalse` and `\@semitwosidefalse`.