# How to set a binding offset with tufte-book class?

Tags: margins, geometry, double-sided, book-design, tufte

I'm typesetting a book using the tufte-book class. For printing I need to set a binding offset (say, 0.5in). However, I can't seem to get this to work using the geometry package settings as one would expect.

The MWE below shows an extreme value set for the odd page, but the even page doesn't shift to the left as expected. Any ideas on how to get this to be symmetrical?

I have tried the answer given in [How to create twoside book with oneside margin?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83695/how-to-create-twoside-book-with-oneside-margin) by godbyk but this breaks the positioning of the footnotes / margin figs etc, and the page number on even pages.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,justified]{tufte-book}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{showframe}

\geometry{landscape,inner=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in,textwidth=5.5in,marginparsep=0.5in,marginparwidth=3.5in,bindingoffset=1in}
% Below from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83695/how-to-create-twoside-book-with-oneside-margin
%\geometry{bindingoffset=30pt, asymmetric, reversemarginpar,landscape,inner=1.5in,top=1in,bottom=1in,textwidth=5.5in,marginparsep=0.5in,marginparwidth=3.5in}

\title{Example Title}

\begin{document}

\mainmatter

\chapter{Example Chapter}

\blindtext[3]\footnote{Testing footnote placement even page}
\blindtext[3]

\section{Example Section}

\blindtext[3]\footnote{Testing footnote placement odd page}

\end{document}
```

**EDIT**

To get a "pseudo `bindingoffset`" I added the following after setting `\geometry`:

```
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{-0.5in}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0.5in}
```

This has the effect of shifting the layout to the left on the even (verso) pages, and the right on the odd (recto) pages.

I would assume this would result in an equal margin between the edge of the page and the text. But it doesn't... So there is an amount of manual adjustment to make it optically 'correct'. This is close:

```
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{-0.3125in}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0.5in}
```

I haven't marked this as an answer as I think there still remains an issue with tufte-book.

Comment: It looks like the combination of the `asymmetric` and `twoside` options kills the `bindingoffset` for the verso page. I'll dig into the logic of the `geometry` package soon and see if I can sort out what's going on.

Comment: Thanks Kevin. All help greatly appreciated. I'll have another go at trying to get this working - maybe stripping out the custom code and maybe re-doing it for this one-off use. That or I'll make my page bigger than A4 and use the crop marks package to decrease the size back to A4 so the printers chop a bit off!

Comment: @godbyk Under pressure to get this book finished I've had to fudge a solution: explicitly setting `\evensidemargin` and `\oddsidemargin` in the preamble after `\geometry` gets me a suitable binding offset for printing. I'll edit the question to give the hint of what to do, but this isn't a true 'fix'.

Comment: This appears to be either a bug in the `geometry` package or a misunderstanding on my part. I've emailed the author of the `geometry` package for clarification. When the `asymmetric` option is used, the `bindingoffset` value appears to be ignored for the verso (left-hand side) pages.

Comment: Yes, that's what I kept seeing... Thanks for the help.

Comment: Hi @godbyk, are there any news yet?

Comment: @Johannes_B, I haven't heard back from Hideo yet.

Comment: Any updates here?