# Two-Sided Gutter in Tufte-LaTeX without symmetric?

Tags: margins, book-design, tufte

The Tufte-LaTeX class has a great "symmetric" option for working on twosided documents (I'm working on a book project), I'd like to explore using this but for now due to the large number of figures I have turning it on is a mess (even using `\forceversofloat` and `\forcerectofloat`).

On the other hand, the Tufte books I have aren't laid out symmetric--the main text block is on the left on both even and odd pages. But to actually print such a book, the gutter would have to be on the right on verso pages and on the left on recto pages. It seems that without using symmetric, there is no gutter; margins are equal on all pages even if using the `twoside` option.

How can I add a gutter margin without using symmetric in Tufte-LaTeX? I've tried `\geometry{hmarginratio=2:3}` and a few other random things, to no avail.

Comment: Is this question a duplicate of [How to set a binding offset with tufte-book class](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/204098/how-to-set-a-binding-offset-with-tufte-book-class)?

Comment: It is! Thanks for finding that @godbyk. By which I mean, thanks for Tufte-LaTeX, it rocks, and so do you :]