# How to place to-do notes in a two-sided document in alternating margins while using the todonotes package?

Tags: margins, double-sided, todonotes

Here's the MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, twoside, titlepage, openright]{report}
\usepackage[left=1.5in, right=1in, top=1in, bottom=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[obeyFinal]{todonotes}

\title{My Title}
\author{}
\date{}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle

    \chapter*{Introduction}

    \todo{To-do note on right page}
    \blindtext

    \newpage
    \todo{To-do note on left page}
    \blindtext
\end{document}
```

A `\reversemarginpar` in the preamble changes the placement from right margin to left margin only once and for the whole document.

So currently I'm forced to use the in-line version of the to-do notes:

```
\todo[inline]{A note}
```

Comment: This solution may help. It is not exactly what you are looking for but it switches location of margins for odd and even pages successfully https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69595/marginnote-always-on-right-side-of-the-page