# paracol with marginnote always on the right side

Tags: margins, double-sided, marginnote, paracol

The goal I am trying to ultimately achieve is a document where I have explanation on even pages and corresponding images on the odd pages.
Normally, I put figure captions, citations and footnotes into the margin using the [tufte-latex](https://ctan.org/pkg/tufte-latex?lang=en) package. There, the margin is always on the right.

Is there a way to have the [marginnote](https://ctan.org/pkg/marginnote) of of twosided document always on the right, when using [paracol](https://ctan.org/pkg/paracol?lang=en)?

Here is a MWE where the `marginnote` is **not** set into the margin.

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}

\let\tuftenote=\marginnote
\let\marginnote\relax% make compatible
\RequirePackage{marginnote}

\usepackage{graphicx, paracol, lipsum, showframe}

\begin{document}
    \begin{paracol}[1]*{2}  
    \switchcolumn[1]\section{Introduction}
    \switchcolumn[0]*
    \switchcolumn[1]
    \marginnote{Bar}
    \lipsum
    \switchcolumn[0]
    \marginnote{Figure 1: Foo}%
    \noindent\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-grid-100x100pt}
    \end{paracol}
\end{document}
```

This is not a problem with `tufte-book`, as I can observe the same effect with `article`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[showframe,
a4paper,
left=24.8mm,
top=27.4mm,
headsep=2\baselineskip,
textwidth=107mm,
marginparsep=8.2mm,
marginparwidth=49.4mm,
textheight=55\baselineskip,
headheight=\baselineskip]{geometry}

\usepackage{graphicx, paracol, marginnote, lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \begin{paracol}[1]*{2}  
    \switchcolumn[1]\section{Introduction}
    \switchcolumn[0]*
    \switchcolumn[1]
    \marginnote{Bar}
    \lipsum
    \switchcolumn[0]
    \marginnote{Figure 1: Foo}%
    \noindent\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-grid-100x100pt}
    \end{paracol}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is the tufte-book version of the MWE.

Comment: So you want paracol to be twosided but the marginpar area to onesided?  I suppose you could use the reverse marginpar area on even pages, but you would need foddpage or some equivalent to tell (`\ifodd\value{page}` is not reliable)..  It might be easier to replace the whole marginotes package.

Comment: Yes, see my edit. There is a [patch](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69595/marginnote-always-on-right-side-of-the-page) for the marginnotes package, but it does not work in combination with paracol.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to do the trick:

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}

\let\tuftenote=\marginnote
\let\marginnote\relax% make compatible
\RequirePackage{marginnote}

\usepackage{graphicx, paracol, lipsum, showframe}

\twosided
\reversemarginpar

\begin{document}
    \begin{paracol}[1]*{2}  
    \switchcolumn[1]\section{Introduction}
    \switchcolumn[0]*
    \switchcolumn[1]
    \marginnote{Bar}
    \lipsum
    \switchcolumn[0]
    \marginnote{Figure 1: Foo}%
    \noindent\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{example-grid-100x100pt}
    \end{paracol}
\end{document}
```